# Requirement Gathering (System Analysis & Design)

Tags: system, system-design, system-analysis

> **Requirement Gathering**
>
> a)    For the initial state of the project, identify ONE method of information gathering (investigation or requirement gathering) that you would use for this system. Discuss the benefits and setbacks method chosen. You are advised to use different methods among group members.
>
> b)    Explain the conduct of the investigation method including how it will be carried-out, target users, location, etc. Create a set of questions that you can use for your investigation. Display the questions only related the system development project.
>
> **System:** Fast Speed Maths Center
>
> **Method of Information Gathering:** Direct and Indirect Observation

I'm completely out of idea how to start, what to write inside the documentation, and what's the format.

Comment: This easily qualifies as too broad - can I ask for some more close votes please?

Answer (score 0):

a) Benefits of using OBSERVATION as method of information gathering.

- exp: Very direct method for collecting data or information – best for the study of human behavior.

b) Visit any maths center, observe what are the people are doing, and set questions that you can use throughout the observation.